# How to know which AWS RDS instance was used before

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Question about the AWS Console.
Is that possible to review the history of RDS instances changes?
For example: previously was used db.m1.small after that upgraded to db.m3.medium.
Maybe there are some logs about that where all these actions were written?

Comment: Do you have AWS Config resource tracking enabled? If not, do you have CloudTrail enabled?

Comment: @MarkB nor of AWS Config and CloudTrail were enabled.

Comment: I don't think you can find the previous value then. You should look into enabling CloudTrail at a minimum. I recommend also using Infrastructure-as-Code to manage your infrastructure, would would have allowed you to look back through version control to see what the previous value was.

Comment: @sabutobi - Questions - (1) Which DB engine you use ? (2) Do you have list of ways/practice your team follows to provision/apply changes to AWS RDS Instance such as manually using AWS Web-Console / aws-cli / AWS CFN / some other CD automation third party tools ? (3) For now, Are you ok with latest 7 days history only?

Comment: @amitd (1) - MySQL Community. (2) - I'm not sure about it. (3) - 7 days history will be fine for me.

Comment: @sabutobi - You can use aws cli command [describe-events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-events.html)

Comment: @amitd thanks for your advice. That didn't help. But I've resolved the issue after your instruction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MarkB and @amitd thanks for your questions.
I'm quite shy about it, but the question was resolved with AWS [support](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/)

General point: if RDS price tier has been changed - you will have some errors at [image: logs & events tab] tab.
But if there were no changes - there will be no logs.